# e.g. is there a way to track textView and edit Text changes in a group of array that consist 3 rows

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, if-statement, android-alertdialog

I am new with kotlin android, and I am working with a TextWatcher that iterate an array within my array blanCustomer it consist rows of a textView where user can input a market and edit text for its quantity.
what i want to execute is to iterate blankCustomer and trace if there is a changes within the edits
but the problem I encountered when I have input in all rows, and i delete the first row textView of the market it should also delete the quantity of that certain row but instead it deletes all of the quantity including the other row.
I know that i may have a error with my iteration
can you suggest a possible solution on how could I implement it correctly?

```
                for (i in 0 until blankCustomerList.count()) {
                    blankCustomerList[i].addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                        override fun afterTextChanged(rowGroup: Editable) {
                            if (rowGroup.isNotBlank()) {
                                enableQuantityEditText()
                            }else{
                                returnQtyToNull()
                            }
                        }

                        override fun beforeTextChanged(rowGroup: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
                        override fun onTextChanged(rowGroup: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                            disableQuantityEditText()
                            newMarketName[i] = rowGroup.toString()
                            blankName[i].kanji = rowGroup.toString()} })
                })
```